# Make navbar scroll along with the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm making a webpage with Bootstrap and I have a navbar on top, and a side navbar using scrollspy for my content. As I scroll down the page, my side navbar doesn't scroll down and stays in it's position. I would like for my side navbar to scroll along with the page so that the user doesn't have to scroll up to access the navbar.

I would like to do the same with my top navbar too. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
        
    <title>Historical Adventures</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #201d1f; position: sticky;" id="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="font-size: 22px">Historical Adventures</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">Placeholder</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-light" href="">Placeholder</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- header -->
    <header class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-light" style="background-color: #262626;">
        <div>
            <center>
                <h1 class="display-3">placeholder</h1>
                <h5 class="lead">placeholder</h5>
            </center>
        </div>
    </header>
    
    <!-- body/content -->
    <div class="container p-0 m-0">
        <div class="row m-0 p-0">
            <!-- side navbar -->
            <div class="col-3 m-0 p-0" style="float: left; position: sticky;">
                
                <nav id="side-navbar" class="navbar navbar-light flex-column p-3 ml-0" style="float: left; background-color: #333333
; border-radius: 10px;">
                    <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                        <div class="mt-2">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#introduction2">Early Civilizations</a>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="mt-2">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#indusvalley">Indus-Valley Civilization</a>
                            <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column ml-3"">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#city-profile">City Profile</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#trade-economy">Trade and Economy</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#cultural-artifacts">Cultural Artifacts</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#administration">Administration</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#indus-script">Indus Script</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#legacy">Legacy</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#conclusion">Conclusion</a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </nav>
                
            </div>


            <!-- main content -->
            <div class="col-9" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#side-navbar" data-bs-offset="0" tabindex="0" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true">
                <!-- content in here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mb-0" style="background-color: #242424;">
        <div>
            <center>
                <a href="#" class="m-1"><i class="fab fa-facebook text-light" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="m-1"><i class="fab fa-instagram text-light" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="m-1"><i class="fab fa- text-light" style="font-size: 24px;"></i></a>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: #202020">
            <h6 class="text-light"><a href="">Website Source Code</a></h6>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

My CSS Code:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #2275e2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: whitesmoke;
}
```

Codepen.io link: https://codepen.io/AverageDogeEnjoyer/pen/vYbLzjw?editors=1010

Comment: @mandy8055 Hi, I'm sorry but I don't know anything about jsfiddle.net and replcating issues there

Comment: @mandy8055 Ok I'll copy paste the code in codepen.io

Comment: @mandy8055 https://codepen.io/AverageDogeEnjoyer/pen/vYbLzjw?editors=1010

Comment: Yes I want it to scroll down too

Comment: Does this help?https://codepen.io/mandy8055/pen/vYbLzaq

Comment: @mandy8055 Yes, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap 4.5 you can set nav bar position to fixed at top by assign **fixed-top** class.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: #201d1f; position: sticky;" id="navbar">
```

For sidebar to make it sticky to top when scroll and remain on screen.you can change top property according to your requirment.

write some custom css to make it sticky.

```
.sidebar {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
 }
```

And assign **.sidebar** class to your sidebar nav.

```
<nav id="side-navbar" class="navbar navbar-light flex-column p-3 ml-0 sidebar" style="float: left; background-color: #333333; border-radius: 10px;">
```